# How I can take latest 5 comments for current user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this tables:

```
Comment
Material1
Material2
User
```

Comment linked with `material1` and `material2` through `morphTo` and linked with `user` through `belongsTo`.

How I can take latest 5 comments for current user in the user's materials?

Answer (score 1):

Use hasManyThrough in conjunction with take(5)